# Question on Banach-Alaoglu theorem: Bounded subset of a set contained in the dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

So the Banach-Alaoglu theorem states:

> Let $X$ be the dual space to some Banach separable space $Z$, i.e
>   $X=Z^*$. Take $M$ a bounded subset of $X$. Then any sequence in $M$
>   has a weak-* convergent subsequence.

**My question is:**

If we know that $Y$ *is contained in* the dual space of some Banach separable space $Z$, then if $M$ is a bounded subset of $Y$, is there still a weak-* convergent subsequence in $Y$?

**The reason I ask is:** 
Let $\Gamma$ be a 2-dimensional compact manifold. I know that the Lebesgue-Bochner space $L^1(0,T,C_c(\Gamma))$ is Banach and separable. It is also known that the dual space of $C_c(\Gamma)$ is the space of Radon measures on $\Gamma$ with finite mass, denoted by $\mathcal M(\Gamma)$. However since $\mathcal M(\Gamma)$ is not separable we can not claim that the dual space of $L^1(0,T, C_c(\Gamma))$ is $L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$. But we do know that $L^1(0,T, C_c(\Gamma))^*$ contains always $L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$. I have a sequence of functions bounded in $L^{\infty}(0,T,L^1(\Gamma))$.

So I wonder if $Y=L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$, $Z=L^1(0,T, C_c(\Gamma))$ and $M=L^{\infty}(0,T,L^1(\Gamma))$, can I deduce a weak-* convergent subsequence then?

It seems true to me but after a lot hours of studying, I would like if somebody else could verify this.

Moreover, if this is not valid, then what can we say in this case? **Is there any other theorem more suitable for that case that I miss at the moment?**

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $Y$? A vector subspace? Could you please specify?

Comment: @pitariver I just edited. Hope it's more clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $(y_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $Y$, you can say that there is a subsequence which weak*-converges to an element of $Z^*$.  But if $Y$ is not weak*-closed in $Z^*$, there is no reason that the limit should be in $Y$.  For instance, if $(y_n)$ itself weak*-converges to a point of $Z^*$ which is not in $Y$, then clearly no subsequence can converge to a point of $Y$.  For an explicit example, you could take $Z=L^1([0,1])$ and $Y=C([0,1])\subset L^\infty([0,1])=Z^*$.  You can then pick a sequence of bounded continuous functions which converge almost everywhere to a discontinuous function like $1_{[0,1/2]}$, and such a sequence will not have any subsequence which weak*-conveges in $Y$.

In your case, $L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$ is weak*-dense in $L^1(0,T, C_c(\Gamma))^*$ so it is not weak*-closed.  It follows (by Krein-Smulian) that there is a bounded sequence in $L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$ which weak*-converges to an element of $L^1(0,T, C_c(\Gamma))^*$ which is not in $L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$.  Such a sequence will have no weak*-convergent subsequence within $L^{\infty}(0,T,\mathcal M(\Gamma))$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!